# How to set pop-up in windows using java?

Tags: java, swing

I have created an application using Swing.
I am trying to create a pop-up notification(not with JOptionPane) with JWindow so that it looks like a windows pop-up notification, and I made that with no error.

The thing is when I link this window to my mainFrame(JFrame) (a mainframe for other purposes and contains the code which will cause this pop-up window to fire), the pop-up notification window looses its position and position become relevant to the mainFrame.

How can I set it to not become relevant to the mainFrame and its postion remain independent ?

Below is the code for pop-up window.

```
popWindow= new JWindow();
popWindow.setLayout(null);

Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension dim= tool.getScreenSize();

int xPos= dim.width - (WIDTH+60);
int yPos= dim.height - (HEIGHT+60);

popWindow.setBounds(xPos, yPos, HEIGHT, WIDTH);

msgLabel= new JLabel("PopUp window");
msgLabel.setBounds(10,0,200,100);

buttonIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\tt\\Desktop\\close_icon.png");
closeButton = new JButton(buttonIcon);
closeButton.setBounds(275,0,25,25);
closeButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
       popWindow.dispose();
   } 
});

popWindow.add(closeButton);
popWindow.add(msgLabel);

popWindow.setVisible(true);
```

I have saved this code in other java file and use its constructor to link this to my mainFrame. When I run it alone, the positioning is perfect.

Comment: Are you asking about the starting display position of the Frame in your monitor screen?

Comment: @user3437460 I didn't get your question ! What do you mean by starting display position ?

Comment: I am asking what do you mean by `How can I set it to not become relevant to the mainFrame and its postion remain independent `

Comment: @user3437460 I have made an application using Swing Code. Its a JFrame with lot of things in it, & I have created a separate class file, let say "popup.java" for the  above code. When I run the code in the file "popup.java" ALONE, it comes on the screen where it is supposed to.
Now when I use this class file in my JFrame code, and I run my JFrame, the position of this pop-up window changes.
So what should I do so that its position remains the same as when I run it alone ?

Comment: `it comes on the screen where it is supposed to` So where this frame you created is supposed to appear in your screen? At the center of your screen? `and I run my JFrame, the position of this pop-up window changes` How was it changed?

Comment: well thanks a lot for your help and time, I managed to change it by changing the positioning itself after linking it to the main code.

However, I will answer your question. When run alone, it comes just above the taskbar on the right,  as I have coded it to. 
When i link it, it comes in the midlle of the screen on the right, and half of the window is out of screen.

Answer (score 0):

//Check the SystemTray is supported
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
            return;
        }
        final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        final TrayIcon trayIcon =
                new TrayIcon(createImage("images/bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
        final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

```
    // Create a pop-up menu components
    MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set auto size");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set tooltip");
    Menu displayMenu = new Menu("Display");
    MenuItem errorItem = new MenuItem("Error");
    MenuItem warningItem = new MenuItem("Warning");
    MenuItem infoItem = new MenuItem("Info");
    MenuItem noneItem = new MenuItem("None");
    MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

    //Add components to pop-up menu
    popup.add(aboutItem);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(cb1);
    popup.add(cb2);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(displayMenu);
    displayMenu.add(errorItem);
    displayMenu.add(warningItem);
    displayMenu.add(infoItem);
    displayMenu.add(noneItem);
    popup.add(exitItem);

    trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    }
```

Comment: this is not what I want right now, but thanks for the help and showing me how to setup system tray !  :)